# Can a programmer change the scancodes of a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm wondering if it is possible to change the actual scan codes that a keyboard generates? I don't mean how they are interpreted (aka remaped), I mean the actual codes that come out of the keyboard.

The reasons.  I have a great little keyboard that took me a long time to find.  It is small, and comfortable, and distinct...  but it has a few keys that I'd like switched out.  Like I never ever ever use prt screen or break, but they are part of the un-functioned set.  The home and end keys are however part of every coders every day...  and they are under the left and right arrow.... (I don't press the "windows" button or the context menu button either)

I switch the keyboard between 3 computers (various sites) and 2 os's, so changing the mapping on the system isn't practical.

Does anyone know where I could go to figure out how to remap the key-scan-codes on the actual hardware(keyboard)?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change the keyboard essentially, either by reprogramming it or swapping the innards out.

This hack acts as a custom HID device and can be used as one example.
http://hackaday.com/2011/10/06/hardware-based-keyboard-remapping/

Otherwise, I think it was well answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410528/is-it-possible-to-reprogram-a-keyboard